How can I compile Emacspeak when I get "failed to set dynamic section sizes: bad value"?
I have trouble getting Emacspeak to work, so I will try to compile it and see if it makes a difference, but of course, I ran into problems compiling it;)
I'm on NixOS.
$ make CXXFLAGS="-fPIC -I/nix/store/1d7l8d6wp74izjxq8q47d2nvg9qy9ald-tcl-8.6.13/include -I/nix/store/l1xbmrjhnw7wh59vlpadryddq0n639c8-espeak-ng-1.51.1/include" LDFLAGS="-L/nix/store/1d7l8d6wp74izjxq8q47d2nvg9qy9ald-tcl-8.6.13/lib -L/nix/store/l1xbmrjhnw7wh59vlpadryddq0n639c8-espeak-ng-1.51.1/lib" espeak
g++ -L/nix/store/1d7l8d6wp74izjxq8q47d2nvg9qy9ald-tcl-8.6.13/lib -L/nix/store/l1xbmrjhnw7wh59vlpadryddq0n639c8-espeak-ng-1.51.1/lib -shared -o tclespeak.so tclespeak.o -ltcl8.6 -lespeak-ng
/nix/store/7v7g86ml0ri171gfcrs1d442px5bi1p3-binutils-2.41/bin/ld: tclespeak.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/nix/store/7v7g86ml0ri171gfcrs1d442px5bi1p3-binutils-2.41/bin/ld: failed to set dynamic section sizes: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [Makefile:27: tclespeak.so] Error 1
Can't build espeak server!

Looking at the Makefile, it indeed uses -fPIC
CXXFLAGS+= -g -O2 -fPIC -DPIC  -pedantic -ansi \
-Wall -Wno-long-long --std=c++11

$(TTS): tclespeak.o
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -shared -o $@ $< $(LIBS)



Did you see recompile with -fPIC? Have you tried that out?

Recompile tclspeak? Isn't tclspeak part of this package? I have not compiled anything else.

I don't know how the package is structured. I'm just going by the error messages you posted, Try removing tclespeak.o and rerun the make. Make sure that when it is compiled, -fPIC is present.

"... when it is compiled ..." - i.e. when the compilation like is something like g++ .... -o tclspeak.o tclespeak.cpp - i.e. when tclespeak.o is produced, not when it is used to build tclespeak.so.

I don't care what the Makefile should do, I only care about what the error message says: just delete the object file and try again and make sure that -fPIC is in the options. On Linux, if I compile with -fPIC, I see (using readelf -S) no .rodata section in the object file; whereas if I compile without -fPIC, there is a .rodata section and the linking step fails with exactly the error message you show.

For completeness, here are the section headers with .rodata in their titles for the -fPIC case: $ readelf -S tclespeak.o | grep rodata   [ 6] .rodata.str1.1    PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00001258   [ 7] .rodata.str1.8    PROGBITS         0000000000000000  000013b8.

Same thing without -fPIC: $ readelf -S tclespeak.o | grep rodata   [ 6] .rodata.str1.1    PROGBITS         0000000000000000  0000114c   [ 7] .rodata.str1.8    PROGBITS         0000000000000000  000012b0   [11] .rodata           PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00001440   [12] .rela.rodata      RELA             0000000000000000  00020218

Any new developments here? Were you able to build tclespeak?

You're right, I deleted the *.o file and it compiles now. The make clean target must not have cleaned it. Thanks a bunch. Not really sure what it was, cause I haven't really done anything;). Anyways, I will probably see the bug again, cause I still have the same issues that originally brought me to compile it;). Thanks again, I'll report back.
